# Creating a re-usable modal object/template system

Tags: javascript, angularjs

We're rewriting an application using Angular 1.2, and I'm trying to determine what the conventional method would be for creating a re-usable dialog.

Our application has several "modal" windows which contain forms. They're opened from multiple places from within our application and are self-contained.

An extremely simple example would be:

```
var userDialog = new app.Dialogs.EditUser({
  user_id: 1,
  save: function(){
    // callback stuff
  }
});
userDialog.show();
```

I'm unsure how best to handle this in Angular. At first I thought about making it a service, but this would have templates for the actual form, etc.

I thought about using a route so I could immediately have a controller/template combo, but I need this content to open up on the current page, without any iframes.

It seems too complex for a directive because it'll control it's own placement in the dom (as a modal, covering everything) and will have some API code letting us get/set some data/options, show/close it, etc.

What's the correct Angular-way of building a re-usable item like this?

Comment: could take a look at how ui-bootstrap modal is implemented: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/modal/modal.js

Comment: I have, but those are all directives which assume you've got the placeholder elements on your page. In this case, I want to programmatically create an instance and show it, I don't want existing elements on the page for this to work.

Comment: you *can* programmatically create/instantiate  bootstrap-ui modals, and use the resolves to pass in whatever data you need to show in the modal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can be inspired by ui-bootstrap (or used it)

documentation: https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal

example: http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview

create a modal window:

```
  var modalInstance = $modal.open({
  templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
  controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
  size: size,
  resolve: {
    items: function () {
      return $scope.items;
    }
  }
});
```

resolve has same meaning as in the router - specify controller locals dependencies.

modalInstance.result is a promise. I think it's a better solution that callbacks ( for example, you can involve result into promise chain).

```
modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
  $scope.selected = selectedItem;
}, function () {
  $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
});
```